# Check other duplicate entry (ies) upon edit but disregard a duplicate in current form

Tags: php, if-statement, pdo, duplicates

I'm kind of new to PDO, and I'm struggling about checking duplicate (s) in the database while I'm on editing form.

The current scenario is:

- The input field is a phone number
- Upon insert it is being checked if it already exist in the db
- Upon edit it is being checked again if the edit got a match in the
  db
- I can't just forbid the editing in the phone number once it is
  added because what if in the future it needs to be change
- After the user hit the edit button all data is being fetch and being
  echoed to its respective fields therefore the user will know that field
  has that kind of information already or that field is still empty

The problem occurs when the user is just editing other fields like "an update for a change in PIN", the phone number field got checked again and obviously it will return an error saying "it already exist".

How can I ignore that field entry if it's not changed?

Here is the part of code for **edit.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['Edith_SIM'])) {
$id = $_POST['id'];
$s_num = $_POST['sim_num'];
$s_net = $_POST['sim_net'];
$s_pn1 = $_POST['simpn1'];
$s_pn2 = $_POST['simpn2'];
$s_pk1 = $_POST['simpk1'];
$s_pk2 = $_POST['simpk2'];
$s_fea = $_POST['sim_feat'];
$s_typ = $_POST['sim_type'];
$s_acq = $_POST['d_acq'];
$s_afo = $_POST['acq_for'];
$s_ufr = $_POST['d_uf'];
$s_uto = $_POST['d_ut'];
$s_dev = $_POST['use_dev'];
$s_sta = $_POST['sim_stat'];
$s_not = $_POST['sim_notes'];

$chekDuplicate = $dbConn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tst_sims WHERE SIM_num= :sim_num');
    $chekDuplicate->execute(array(':sim_num' => $s_num));

// checking empty fields
if(empty($s_num)) {                
    echo "<font color='red'>Must have SIM number my dudes</font><br/>";
    echo "<br/><a href='javascript:self.history.back();'>Go Back</a>";
} elseif($chekDuplicate->rowCount() > 0) {
    echo "<font color='red'>Its existing my dudes</font><br/>";
    echo "<br/><a href='javascript:self.history.back();'>Go Back</a>";
} else { 
    $sim_passed_e = "UPDATE tst_sims SET 
    SIM_num = :sim_num,
    SIM_network =:sim_net,
    SIM_PIN1 =:simpn1,
    SIM_PIN2 =:simpn2,
    SIM_PUK1 =:simpk1,
    SIM_PUK2 =:simpk2,
    SIM_features =:sim_feat,
    SIM_type =:sim_type,
    Acquired =:d_acq,
    Acquired_for =:acq_for,
    Used_from =:d_uf,
    Used_to =:d_ut,
    Used_devices =:use_dev,
    Status =:sim_stat,
    Notes =:sim_notes
    WHERE Ent_id =:id";

$que_edit = $dbConn->prepare($sim_passed_e); 

            $que_edit->bindparam(':id', $id);
            $que_edit->bindparam(':sim_num', $s_num);
            $que_edit->bindparam(':sim_net', $s_net);
            $que_edit->bindparam(':simpn1', $s_pn1);
            $que_edit->bindparam(':simpn2', $s_pn2);
            $que_edit->bindparam(':simpk1', $s_pk1);
            $que_edit->bindparam(':simpk2', $s_pk2);
            $que_edit->bindparam(':sim_feat', $s_fea);
            $que_edit->bindparam(':sim_type', $s_typ);
            $que_edit->bindparam(':d_acq', $s_acq);
            $que_edit->bindparam(':acq_for', $s_afo);
            $que_edit->bindparam(':d_uf', $s_ufr);
            $que_edit->bindparam(':d_ut', $s_uto);
            $que_edit->bindparam(':use_dev', $s_dev);
            $que_edit->bindparam(':sim_stat', $s_sta);
            $que_edit->bindparam(':sim_notes', $s_not);
            $que_edit->execute();

    header("location: index.php");
    echo "<font color='green'>Data added successfully my dudes.";
    echo "<br/><a href='index.php'>View Result</a>";
}
}
```

I hope this is not that confusing to all of you, I don't know what kind of approach I should make to this.

Comment: Send to server only id and changed fields.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the current ID in duplicate check.

```
$chekDuplicate = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tst_sims WHERE SIM_num= :sim_num, id != :id");
$chekDuplicate->execute([':sim_num' => $s_num, ':id' => $id]);
```

It does not matter whether sim number is changed or not, simply this sim number should not be used by any other user except current user who is updating this record and we are good.

Comment: @ailia, if this works for you, do accept and vote up the answer. :)

Comment: sorry about the delay of reply...
im getting an error

Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' id != '#idnumber'

how everi if I do -- SIM_num= :sim_num AND id != :id" , it proceeds like not checking at all.

Comment: anyways, i did not got my self stuck on this (i proceeded) to other phase of dev for a moment, i am reconsidering on - how about I made a separate form just for the SIM number. like the style of JS kind of edit page where you edit on input fields at a time and when your cursor got out of focus on that field it will consider that its summited without reloading the page.